# Lua - Array indexed by vector

Tags: arrays, vector, lua

It seems like arrays indexed by vectors are not index by the value of the vector but by the address of the vector. An example:

```
local a = vmath.vector3(1,2,3)
    local b = vmath.vector3(1,2,3)
    test = {}
    test[a] = 1
    print(a==b, test[a], test[b])
```

prints "true, 1, nil"

Is this normal behavior? How can I index an array with a value instead of the adress?

Comment: Convert vector to string `"1.0;2.0;3.0"` and use this string as table key.

Comment: Is there a reverse function of the function "tostring"? Or do I have to code the "tostring, fromstring", myself?

Comment: After "fromstring" you will get ANOTHER vector with the same components.  Is it OK for you?

Comment: Yes it would be perfect.

Comment: The index operator can be [overridden](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4). [Torch](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md) does it like this: `a[{1,2,3}]`

Answer (score 0):

As Egor Skriptunoff mentionned it in the comments, the solution is to convert vectors to strings using tostring() for instance

Comment: Please note that on Lua 5.3 equal integer and float numbers may be converted to different strings: `"2" and "2.0"`.

Comment: Thanks for the note. However in this particular example, my vectors contain integers.